# ccmenuitem from another layer cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I've seen an [example](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/16065) on cocos2d forum with accessing sprites from different layer but tried and it doesn't working; maybe I'm not doing something as I should

For the scene method I have:

```
+(CCScene *)scene {

    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    CurrentLayer *_currentLayer = [CurrentLayer node];
    aLayer *_aLayer = [aLayer node];
    [scene addChild: _currentLayer z:0 tag: 128];
    [scene addChild: _aLayer z:1 tag:288];

return scene;

}
```

I'm trying to access a `CCMenuItem` from `aLayer` in `CurrentLayer`, the way I do is:

```
    CCMenuItem *menuItemToBeAccessed = (CCMenuItem *)[[[self parent] getChildByTag:288] getChildByTag:60];
```

In aLayer I've placed my `CCMenuItem` in this way:

```
        menuItem = [[CCMenuItemSprite
                     itemFromNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"menuItemImage.png"]
                     selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"menuItemImage.png"]
                     target:self
                     selector:@selector(methodToBeCalled:)] retain];
        // the reason that I'm keeping my menu item disabled is that I want to enable when I press another ccmenuitem in the other layer
        menuItem.isEnabled = NO;
        menuItem.tag = kMenuItem; // which is added in enum as:  kMenuItem = 60
        [menuItem setAnchorPoint: ccp(0,0)];
        menuObject = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuItem, nil];
        [menuObject setPosition: ccp(menuObject_X, menuObject_Y)];
        [self addChild:menuObject z:5];
```

How the path to my `CCMenuItem` would look like?

UPDATE:

```
GamePlay->ParallaxLayers->aLayer
     access bLayer from aLayer
```

You've pointed me to:

```
CCMenuItem *bCCMenuItem = (CCMenuItem *)[(CCMenu *)[[self.parent getChildByTag:kLayerTag] getChildByTag:kMenuTag] getChildByTag:kMenuItemTag];


GamePlay->ParallaxLayers->bLayer
     access aLayer from bLayer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite any facts about the way you're trying to access a menu item from another layer, you're missing the fact that your CCMenuItem is a child of your CCMenu.

You would need to access the CCMenu and then, access it's child CCMenuItem by tag.

Something like:

```
CCMenuItem *toBeAccessed = (CCMenuItem *)[(CCMenu *)[[self.parent getChildByTag:kLayerTag] getChildByTag:kMenuTag] getChildByTag:kMenuItemTag];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but still doesn't work, I've output the toBeAccessed `CCMenuItem` to `CCLOG` and its `(null)` ; Any clue what might be?

Comment: Try logging each step of the way to see where it gets nil'd. After the first one every other will be the same.
The CCMenuItem as child of the CCMenu is for sure, just make sure you're getting the right item on every step of the way.
parent->layer->menu->item

Comment: a strange thing is that when I'm output the parent like this: `CCLOG(@"%@", [self parent]);`, it gives me: `CCParallaxNode = 0181A050 | Tag = 1` (because my layers are added to a parallaxNode) and the `parallaxNode` is added to `parallaxLayers` CCLayer and the `parallaxLayers` CCLayer is added to the gamePlay layer. Getting the menu items its relative to the layer where I'm trying to get the menu item or to the Root layer?

Comment: You'll need to go up until you reach the parent of your CCMenu. Right now the only one who can be sure about which that is, is you. Once you reach that, just do as I wrote in my answer and you should be able to reach the CCMenuItem.